# Sql server 2008 R2 fail over cluster

Tags: sql-server-2008, failovercluster

I want to be sure something about sql server 2008 fail over clustering. I heard that when i set two sql servers as failover cluster servers i can set load level of sql servers. for examples i have SQL-A and SQL-B as failovered sql servers. SQL-A will process requests. SQL-B will wait. when SQL-A reached to %80 CPU load SQL-B will start to answer requests. Is that correct? this feature is sql server's feature or windows server's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone has terribly misinformed you. MS clustering is only failover : that means that if A is active, it owns the cluster resources : storage, IP, and database services. B just sits there, twiddling its thumbs, until A dies. Then, B will take over the resources.